# How to write this statement in jquery name = "@{User.Identity.GetUserName();}";

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor

I want to get the current user name from my page and to use it in jquery, but when I excecute this I get an empty string...

Statement(Jquery + asp.net(mvc c#)):

> var name = "@{User.Identity.GetUserName();}";

Thanks...

Comment: this is not jquery specific, what does `alert("@{User.Identity.GetUserName();}")` output?

Comment: Its c# and jquery. The user name from the server and than it will be send to the client, with the current user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{User.Identity.GetUserName();}
```

denotes a code block in razor. You can output the name by using

```
var name = "@User.Identity.GetUserName()";
```

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
var name = "@(User.Identity.GetUserName())";
```

Comment: "Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected" this is the error

Comment: can you try as var name = "@(User.Identity.GetUserName())"; "Remove Colon"

Answer (score 1):

you syntax should be like this, paste this code on your view and run that view you will see an alert:

```
@{
string abc="vinay singh";
```

}

with in script panel on your view write this...

```
alert('my name is '+'@(abc)');
```

==============

one point you should noted here that 
var name = "@{User.Identity.GetUserName();}"; will work only if you write your js script block with in your view, but if you write this in seperate js file this won't be work

Regards